# what does this mean in this php script ? $row[$i]=&$row[$i]; it seems $row is getting a reference of itself,it doesn`t make sence

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

table structure:8 cols a simple emploee info table

```
CREATE TABLE `emp2` (
    `empno` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `ename` text,
    `job` text,
    `mgr` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `hiredate` text,
    `sal` double DEFAULT NULL,
    `comm` double DEFAULT NULL,
    `deptno` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`empno`),
    UNIQUE KEY `pk_emp` (`empno`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

test csvfile:a test emp.csv file

```
7369,SMITH,CLERK,7902,"1980-12-23 00:00:00",800,,20
7499,ALLEN,SALSMAN,7698,"1980-12-23 00:00:00",1600,300,30
7521,WARD,SALESMAN,7698,"1980-12-23 00:00:00",1250,500,30
```

php script: i removed most thorw Exception codes to make it shorter
i can understand that array_unshift($row ,$fmt),is to make the $row something like this below ,so the valid data is from position 1 to 8 .

```
array(9) {
   [0] =>
   string(8) "ssssssss"
   [1] =>
   string(4) "7934"
   [2] =>
   string(6) "MILLER"
   [3] =>
   string(5) "CLERK"
   [4] =>
   string(4) "7782"
   [5] =>
   string(19) "1980-12-23 00:00:00"
   [6] =>
   string(4) "1300"
   [7] =>
   string(0) ""
   [8] =>
   string(2) "10"
}

<?php
$tname = 'emp';
$fname = 'emp.csv';
$rownum = 0;
function create_insert_stmt($table, $ncols)
{//create insert sql
    $stmt = "insert into " . $table . " values(";
    foreach (range(1, $ncols) as $i) {
        $stmt .= " ? ,";
    }
    $stmt = preg_replace("/,$/", ');', $stmt);
    return $stmt;
}

try {
    $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'scott');
    $db->autocommit(FALSE);
    $res = $db->prepare("select * from " . $tname);
    $ncols = $res->field_count;
    $res->free_result();
    $ins = create_insert_stmt($tname, $ncols);
    $fmt = str_repeat("s", $ncols);
    $res = $db->prepare($ins);
    $fp = new SplFileObject($fname, "r");
    while ($row = $fp->fgetcsv()) {
        if (strlen(implode('', $row)) == 0) continue;
        array_unshift($row, $fmt);//put 'ssssssss' into array $row
        foreach (range(1, $ncols) as $i) {
            $row[$i] =& $row[$i];
            //what does this mean ,when i remove & why it can`t work
        }
        call_user_func_array(array(&$res, "bind_param"), $row);
        //the original code is :
        //call_user_func_array(array(&$res,"bind_param"),&$row);
        //it seems i can`t use &$row in php5.6,so i removed & then it worked fine
        $res->execute();

        $rownum++;
    }
    $db->commit();
    print $rownum . "rows inserted into " . $tname . "\n<br>";

} catch (Exception $e) {
    print "exception:";
    die($e->getMessage() . '\n<br>');
}
```

Comment: @MawiaHL how in hell are they even close from duplicates ?  I mean, basically the question asked is stated in the title : why is this variable set to a reference to itself, while the "duplicate" ask what does =& do, so how can you state that they could be duplicate ? and people flag this comment as usefull ...

Answer (score 1):

according to : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Object oriented style

bool mysqli_stmt::bind_param ( string $types , mixed &$var1 [, mixed &$... ] )
Procedural style

bool mysqli_stmt_bind_param ( mysqli_stmt $stmt , string $types , mixed &$var1 [, mixed &$... ] )

the parameters of the bind_param functions are all references,

so ,it`s clear that $row[$i]=&$row[$i] is getting reference of itself.

what confused me is that :what exactly is getting reference of itself?
is it Copy-On-Write thing? Or initinalize the array in the memory?
$row is generated by $fp->getcsv(),so it should already exsit in memeory

Comment: well it's not a "reference to itself" as a particular php concept, it's just a reference to what it was before it changed to a reference, so it's just a basic reference

Comment: it's just a reference to what it was before it changed to a reference??I still don`t get it ,for e.g                                                                                                  $a=4;                                                                                                                       $b=&$a;                                                                                                                     $b=5; //now both $a and $b are 5 ,$b stores the location of $a in memory

Comment: so is it like this?                                                                                                      $row[0]=1;//now $row[0] stores int 1                                                                                                                     $row[0]=&$row[0];//now $row[0] stores the location points to int 1                         is this right?

Comment: yes that's just it